# If $A_n$ is a sequence of self-adjoint nonnegative operators with $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left\|A_n\right\|}n\le0$, does $|A_n|^{-n}$ converge?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space. Note that if $A\in\mathfrak L(H)$, then $A^\ast A$ is nonnegative and self-adjoint and hence $$|A|:=\sqrt{A^\ast A}$$ is well-defined.

Now let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathfrak L(H)$ with $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left\|A_n\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}}n\le0.$$ Are we able to conclude that $\left(|A_n|^{\frac1n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent and the limiting operator $A$ is nonnegative and self-adjoint as well? If each $A_n$ is compact, will $A$ be compact as well?

**EDIT**: I guess we need further assumptions. What I want to achieve is a generalization of Proposition 1.3 in the paper [Ergodic theory of differentiable dynamical systems](http://www.ihes.fr/~ruelle/PUBLICATIONS/%5B59%5D.pdf):

$^1$
[image]

I guess the "$\wedge q$" is a notation for the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_form#Wedge_product). How can we generalize this condition?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't have oscillation here. e.g. if $A_n$ and $B_n$ are both sequences satisfying your conditions such that $|A_n|^{-n}\rightarrow A$ and $|B_n|^{-n}\rightarrow B$, then you could define $C_n=\begin{cases}A_n&n \mbox{even}\\B_n&n\mbox{odd}\end{cases}$, in which case $|C_n|^{-n}$ would only converge if $A=B$.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I guess we need further assumption; please see my edit.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I've just noticed that I've mistakenly written $|A_n|^{-n}$, but it should clearly be $|A_n|^{\frac1n}$. Sorry for that.